# Modules over $k[X,Y]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Over a PID like $k[X]$, all (non-trivial) ideals are free and hence projective. But the ring $k[X,Y]$ is not a PID. Is it possible to describe all ideals of this particular ring which are projective modules?

(What if we restrict to $k$ algebraically closed? ...)

Comment: Every finitely generated projective module over a polynomial ring is free. See the [Quillen–Suslin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Suslin_theorem), formely known as Serre's conjecture.

Comment: @lhf: well, yes. Do you mean something  different from what I said in my answer?

Comment: @Georges, no I don't. The question reminded me at once of Serre's conjecture and I just wanted to mention the link to the Quillen-Suslin theorem.

Comment: @lhf:  Thank you for the link to the Quillen-Suslin theorem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $k$ is a field the ideals $I\subset A=k[X,Y]$ which are projective modules over $A$ are *exactly* the principal ideals.
Indeed every projective module over $A$ is free and a free  ideal in a domain can only be of dimension $0$ or $1$, because two non-zero elements $f,g$ are always  linearly dependent: $g.f+ (-f).g=0$ !

So the free (= projective) ideals in $A$  are $I=(0)$ with $dim_A(0)=0 $ and $I=fA, \; f\neq 0$ with $dim_A (fA)=1$ (where $\lbrace f \rbrace $ is a basis of $I$).

Since I'm in an aggressive mood [:-)], I'll use a sledge-hammer to justify my claim above that $I$ is free if it is projective: the  Quillen-Suslin theorem, which indeed says that any finitely generated projective module over a polynomial ring $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ ($ k$ a field) is free.

**Edit**
 I'm in a more peaceful mood now, and I'll give a more elementary argument that projective implies free.
If a non-zero  ideal in a domain is projective, it must be projective of rank one (this is proved in Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative,chap.II, §5, Théorème 4).
And now you just use that projective modules *of rank one* in a UFD are free (in geometric language: the Picard group of a UFD is trivial. You can find that in [this book by Görtz-Wedhorn](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_geometry_I.html?id=XEiLudn6sq4C), on page 309).

Comment: Ok... Uhm, I didn't expect the big machinery, to be honest :). Is there an easy/elementary way to see that - for example - the non-principal ideal $(X,Y)$ is not projective?

Comment: The ideal $\mathfrak m=(X,Y)$ is not *locally* free, hence not projective. Indeed $\mathfrak m A_{\mathfrak m}$ is not free as an $A_{\mathfrak m}$- module: this uses no big machinery.

Answer (score 5):

One can show that the maximal ideal $M=(x,y)$ is not projective without using [Quillen–Suslin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Suslin_theorem), but I'll at least assume tensor products and [flat modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) (projectives are a special case of flats, flats are the limits of projectives).

In fact, $M$ is not even flat: $M \otimes M \to M^2$ is not injective since $x\otimes y - y \otimes x \mapsto xy-yx = 0$.  One looks at this modulo $M^2$ to see that $M/M^2$ is a nonzero vector space (of dimension 2) over $k$, and so the tensor product is nonzero, but the range is then obviously 0.

Comment: Dear Jack, although $M$ is indeed not flat, I don't understand your arguments. Why is $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$ not zero? And  how can you "look at this   modulo $M^2$", since  $M^2$ is definitely not included in $M \otimes M$ ?

Comment: @Georges: If x⊗y−y⊗x = 0 in M⊗M, then it is 0 in every quotient, including the quotient by $M^2 \cdot ( M\otimes M)$, which is isomorphic to $R/M^2 \otimes (M \otimes M) \cong M/M^2 \otimes M/M^2 \cong k^2 \otimes k^2 \cong k^4 \neq 0$.  If one traces the isomorphisms, x⊗x = e11, x⊗y = e12, y⊗x = e21, y⊗y = e22, and so of course e12 - e21 ≠ 0.

Comment: Dear Jack: thank you for your convincing explanations.